# socket.io object has no method 'emit'

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am getting this error message

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'emit'

when trying to access a socket in `helpQue`, which is constructed with `helpQue.push(socket)`.

Both `helpQue` and `cxsQue` are arrays of sockets.

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(helpQue.length > 0 && cxsQue.length > 0) {
        var id = makeid(),
            helpee = helpQue.splice(0, 1);

            helpee.emit('server-output', 'Test'); //ERROR here
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched the code to

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(helpQue.length > 0 && cxsQue.length > 0) {
        var id = makeid(),
            helpee = helpQue[0];
            helpQue.splice(0, 1);

            helpee.emit('server-output', 'Test');
    }
}, 1000);
```

it worked. I assume there was something going on with `splice`, but can't figure out what. If anyone knows please let me know.